# Fallo insertar datos con ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tendiendo problemas con la inserción de datos en una tabla a la hora de hacerlo con ajax

No veo que estoy haciendo mal para que me ponga en la consola undefined y no procese la petición.

index

```
<form action="" id="formulario_inscripciones">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <label>Teléfono</label>
    <input name="telefono" id="telefono">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email">
    <select name="FK_id_actividades" id="FK_id_actividades">
        <option value ="1">Ecoboat</option>
        
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id='inscripciones' onclick='inscipciones()' >Inscribirse</button>
    
</form>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
var $telefono = document.getElementById('telefono');
var $email = document.getElementById('email');
var $FK_id_actividades = document.getElementById('FK_id_actividades');
function inscripciones() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insercion_actividades.php",
      data: {
        nombre: $nombre.value,
        telefono: $telefono.value,
        email: $email.value,
        FK_id_actividades: $FK_id_actividades.value
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

PHP

```
$nombre="";
$email="";
$telefono="";
$FK_id_actividades="";

if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
}
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email=$_POST["email"];
}
if(isset($_POST["telefono"])){
    $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
}
if(isset($_POST["FK_id_actividades"])){
    $FK_id_actividades=$_POST["FK_id_actividades"];
}

 $insert = "INSERT INTO actividades ( id, nombre, email, telefono, FK_id_actividades) VALUES (null,:nombre, :email, :telefono, :FK_id_actividades)";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($insert);
        $statement->execute(array(
            
            ':nombre' => $nombre,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':telefono' => $telefono,
            ':FK_id_actividades' => $FK_id_actividades
        ));
```

Comment: El tipo de control que haces con los isset de ese modo no es coherente. Si algún dato viaja en blanco, la variable de ese dato será `Undefined` cuando intentes usarla en el `execute()`... Aunque este no sea necesariamente el motivo del problema actual, deberías considerarlo para dar solidez a tu código. De todos modos, no  veo que haya respuesta desede PHP. Debes poner un `echo`  de algo para que Ajax reciba datos. Podrías por ejemplo controlar si hay filas insertadas y emitir un mensaje: `echo "Se insertó el registro";`  o algo así.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable mezclar Javascript puro con jQuery, dificulta la legibilidad y podría ser causa de errores o comportamiento inesperado. Además, recuerda que en Javascript no es necesario el uso de `$` para nombrar las variables. Con ambas recomendaciones, las variables que se refieren a elementos del DOM, como esta:

```
var $nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
```

Deberían simplificarse a:

```
var nombre = $('#nombre');
```

Revisando tu código original, , haciendo un `console.log()` de las variables declaradas, no encontré la causa de ese `undefined`.

Pero, tampoco es necesario declarar variables con elementos de formulario para enviar por AJAX; es más fácil y apropiado crear un [objeto FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) y proporcionar el formulario para que agregue automáticamente todos los campos.

Solo hay que hacer algunas modificaciones en la petición AJAX:

- El símbolo `$` se usa como alias de `jQuery`, por ejemplo, `$.ajax()` en vez de `jQuery.ajax()`, a menos que haya otro script que pueda estar ocasionando conflictos.
- Cambiar propiedad `type` por `method`; no es estrictamente necesario, pero lo que realmente se usa para la petición es `method` y el primero es un alias.
- Proporcionar el objeto `FormData` para enviar los campos del formulario.
- Agregar la propiedad `processData` en falso para evitar que jQuery convierta los datos en cadenas del tipo `campo=valor`.
- Agregar la propiedad `error` con una función para ver en consola cualquier mensaje de error y saber qué es lo que debes hacer para corregir. En este fragmento de código no se ejecuta la petición porque no es posible encontrar la URL especificada y, aparte, hay limitaciones por cuestiones de seguridad.

```js
// Ejecutar cuando se cargue el DOM
$(function() {
    // Escuchar evento submit en formulario
    $('#formulario_inscripciones').on('submit', inscripciones);
});

function inscripciones() {
    // Evitar que el formulario se procese de forma normal (recarga de página)
    event.preventDefault();
    // Incluir todos los campos del formulario
    // - $(this) es el objeto jQuery que maneja el formulario
    // - El primer elemento del objeto [0] hace referencia al formulario en el DOM
    let data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    // Solo para probar que están todos
    console.log(...data);
    // ******** IMPORTANTE ******
    // Deberías validar que no hay variables vacías antes de ejecutar la petición
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST", // "type" es un alias de "method"
      url: "insercion_actividades.php",
      data: data, // Enviar los datos del formulario
      processData: false, // Datos como objeto, no convertir a cadena
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, message) {
        console.log(`Error en petición: ${status} - ${message}`);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="formulario_inscripciones">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <label>Teléfono</label>
    <input name="telefono" id="telefono">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" id="email">
    <select name="FK_id_actividades" id="FK_id_actividades">
        <option value ="1">Ecoboat</option>
        
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id='inscripciones'>Inscribirse</button>
    
</form>
```

En PHP estás creando las variables necesarias correctamente:

```
$nombre="";
$email="";
$telefono="";
$FK_id_actividades="";

if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
}
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email=$_POST["email"];
}
if(isset($_POST["telefono"])){
    $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
}
if(isset($_POST["FK_id_actividades"])){
    $FK_id_actividades=$_POST["FK_id_actividades"];
}
```

Pero puedes simplificar con asignación ternaria o el [operador de fusión null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? '';
$email = $_POST["email"] ?? '';
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"] ?? '';
$FK_id_actividades = $_POST["FK_id_actividades"] ?? 0;
```

Para evitar registros vacíos, debes validar los datos; en este ejemplo solo se revisa que no estén vacíos, pero deberías verificar formatos de correo electrónico y teléfono.

```
if(empty($nombre) || empty($email) || empty($telefono) || $FK_id_actividades <= 0) {
    // Finalizar con mensaje de error
    die('Uno o más campos están vacíos');
}
// Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar
```